# Strange Behaviour with Order by Limit Postgres12

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, limit, postgresql-12

I have a query like:

```
SELECT ed.Entity_Data_sur_id
FROM ucc.Entity_Data ed
WHERE   ed.entity_id = 1
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

which returns:

```
entity_data_sur_id
10021351
10020351
10019351
10018351
10017351
10016351
10015351
```

but when adding limit 1

```
SELECT ed.Entity_Data_sur_id
FROM ucc.Entity_Data ed
WHERE   ed.entity_id = 1
ORDER BY timestamp DESC limit 1
```

I am getting

```
entity_data_sur_id
6001351
```

Is this a bug in PostgreSQL12?

Comment: What data type is `entity_data_sur_id`

Comment: Are `timestamp` values alone sufficient to *uniquely* order the rows? I.e. that no two rows share the same `timestamp` value? If not, you've given the system freedom to be arbitrary in the rows it selects among equal values.

Comment: entity_data_sur_id is a serial data type

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You are right, i just figured that out. I am closing this question

Comment: What is result from: `select * from ucc.Entity_Data where timestamp = (select max(timestamp) from ucc.Entity_Data where entity_id = 1);`